# Where does James come from?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Am I supposed to know who James Vega is?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54510/am-i-supposed-to-know-who-james-vega-is)

James just struck me when I started the game with him? Who is he? Where does he come from? Why is he, all of a sudden, in my crew?

Bottom-line: WHO THE HELL IS THIS GUY?

Comment: He's [Freddie Prinze, Jr.](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0005327/), duh ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vega was tasked with gaurding Shepard while Shepard was in 'prison' on earth. When the reapers attacked he helped Ash/Kaiden get to the Normandy and helped them pick you up. So he is in your crew by pure chance.